# Regex extract info between two comma

Tags: regex, r, gsub

```
data<-data.frame(x=c("a,b","c","a,b","d,e,f,g"))
        x
1     a,b
2       c
3     a,b
4 d,e,f,g
```

I would like to extract info from column x and write every unique info into column y, what should I do? Thank you! Col y is expected like:

```
  y
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 f
7 g
```

Comment: Regex is not really needed here.  Something like `unique(scan(text=as.character(data$x), sep=",", what=""))` would probably do it.  `strsplit()` would be another option.

Comment: Or using `strsplit`. For example : `unlist(strsplit(as.character(data$x),","))`

Comment: If the data is just comma separated, there is no need for  a regex, really. Otherwise, it could look like `y <- unique(unlist(str_extract_all(data$x, "[^,]+")))` or something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
d<-data.frame(x=c("a,b","c","a,b","d,e,f,g"))

> levels(d$x)
[1] "a,b"     "c"       "d,e,f,g"

> e <- as.character(levels(d$x))
> e
[1] "a,b"     "c"       "d,e,f,g"
> 

> f <- strsplit(e,",")
> f
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "c"

[[3]]
[1] "d" "e" "f" "g"

unlist(f)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyr` solution:

```
library(tidyr)
data %>% unnest(x=strsplit(as.character(x),",")) %>% unique()
```

or (thanks to @alistaire)

```
data %>% separate_rows(x) %>% unique()
```

Comment: Hadley wrote a wrapper for that structure in 0.5.0: `data %>% separate_rows(x) %>% unique()`

Comment: thanks, I thought I'd seen something that go by, but couldn't find it